# Problems with GL_LUMINANCE and ATI

Tags: opengl, glsl, luminance

I'm trying to use luminance textures on my ATI graphics card.

*The problem*: I'm not being able to correctly retrieve data from my GPU. Whenever I try to read it (using glReadPixels), all it gives me is an 'all-ones' array (1.0, 1.0, 1.0...).

You can test it with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

static int arraySize = 64;
static int textureSize = 8;
//static GLenum textureTarget = GL_TEXTURE_2D;
//static GLenum textureFormat = GL_RGBA;
//static GLenum textureInternalFormat = GL_RGBA_FLOAT32_ATI;
static GLenum textureTarget = GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB;
static GLenum textureFormat = GL_LUMINANCE;
static GLenum textureInternalFormat = GL_LUMINANCE_FLOAT32_ATI;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // create test data and fill arbitrarily
    float* data = new float[arraySize];
    float* result = new float[arraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i + 1.0;
    }

    // set up glut to get valid GL context and
    // get extension entry points
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("TEST1");
    glewInit();

    // viewport transform for 1:1 pixel=texel=data mapping
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, textureSize, 0.0, textureSize);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, textureSize, textureSize);

    // create FBO and bind it (that is, use offscreen render target)
    GLuint fboId;
    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fboId);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fboId);

    // create texture
    GLuint textureId;
    glGenTextures (1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(textureTarget, textureId);

    // set texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

    // define texture with floating point format
    glTexImage2D(textureTarget, 0, textureInternalFormat, textureSize, textureSize, 0, textureFormat, GL_FLOAT, 0);

    // attach texture
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, textureTarget, textureId, 0);

    // transfer data to texture
    //glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
    //glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
    //glDrawPixels(textureSize, textureSize, textureFormat, GL_FLOAT, data);
    glBindTexture(textureTarget, textureId);
    glTexSubImage2D(textureTarget, 0, 0, 0, textureSize, textureSize, textureFormat, GL_FLOAT, data);

    // and read back
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, textureSize, textureSize, textureFormat, GL_FLOAT, result);

    // print out results
    printf("**********************\n");
    printf("Data before roundtrip:\n");
    printf("**********************\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        printf("%f, ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");

    printf("**********************\n");
    printf("Data after roundtrip:\n");
    printf("**********************\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        printf("%f, ", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // clean up
    delete[] data;
    delete[] result;

    glDeleteFramebuffersEXT (1, &fboId);
    glDeleteTextures (1, &textureId);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

I also read somewhere on the internet that ATI cards don't support luminance yet. Does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: You need to provide some actual code. Preferably the code you're actually running. A link to the index for a giant set of tutorials is not helpful. At least link to the one you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what I found out:

1) If you use GL_LUMINANCE as texture format (and GL_LUMINANCE_FLOAT32_ATI GL_LUMINANCE32F_ARB or GL_RGBA_FLOAT32_ATI as internal format), the glClampColor(..) (or glClampColorARB(..)) doesn't seem to work at all. 
I was only able to see the values getting actively clamped/not clamped if I set the texture format to GL_RGBA. I don't understand why this happens, since the only glClampColor(..) limitation I heard of is that it works exclusively with floating-point buffers, which all chosen internal formats seems to be.

2) If you use GL_LUMINANCE (again, with GL_LUMINANCE_FLOAT32_ATI, GL_LUMINANCE32F_ARB or GL_RGBA_FLOAT32_ATI as *internal* format), it looks like you must "correct" your output buffer dividing each of its elements by 3. I guess this happens because when you use glTexImage2D(..) with GL_LUMINANCE [it internally replicates each array component three times](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) and when you read GL_LUMINANCE values with glReadPixel(..) [it calculates its values from the sum of the RGB components](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) (thus, three times what you have given as input). But again, it stills give you clamped values.

3) Finally, if you use GL_RED as texture format (instead of GL_LUMINANCE), you don't need to pack your input buffer and you get your output buffer properly. The values are not clamped and you don't need to call glClampColor(..) at all.

So, I guess I'll stick with GL_RED, because in the end what I wanted was an easy way to send and collect floating-point values from my "kernels" without having to worry about offsetting array indexes or anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with luminance values; the problem is with you reading floating point values.

In order to read floating-point data back properly via glReadPixels, you first need to [set the color clamping mode](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glClampColor). Since you're obviously not using OpenGL 3.0+, you should be looking at the [ARB_color_buffer_float extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/color_buffer_float.txt). In that extension is `glClampColorARB`, which works pretty much like the core 3.0 verison.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I did some testing and came to some conclusions which I found would be better put if I post them as an answer rather than a comment.